# Не подключаются стили в общий файл scss

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, файлы, scss

у меня есть следующая файловая структура:

[image: файловая структура]

Общий файл со стилями выглядит так:

[image: общий файл]

Проблема в том, что файлы со стилями не видят общих стилей, например миксинов и переменных. В чем моя ошибка подключения?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: а пробовали расширение добавить в путь импорта? Просто у вас есть и vars.css и vars.scss